# how to customize the color of frame and title area of HUD panel

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, hud

I need to let the user to customize the HUD window appearance. Is there a way to change the frame and the title area color of HUD window? There is an API for changing a background color of the window, but title and the frame stay semitransparent black. I'd like to avoid drawing these areas by myself.

Thanks,

Nava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case nobody knows, I found a couple of links that do it. One of them is a Synapse project, which shows how to use private headers and draws the window by itself. Definitely it's not straight forward and IMO should be allowed by native interfaces. Many thanks to the guy that wrote it:
[Synapse project](http://thesynapseproject.org/blog.php?p=3)